# When using Generics types and ModelSerializer, how can I Serialize an Inherited class instead of the Base class in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

## **Context:**

##### models.py

Let's say I have a Generic Django Model class called **"Base"** to group all other classes that extend it:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True
    )
```

And the class **"Company"**, that extends the **"Base"**:

```
class Company(Base)
    pass  # It just extends the Base Attributes.
```

The class **"Manager"**, also extends **"Base" but it has a role attribute**:

```
class Manager(Base)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE ...)
```

And the class **"Worker"**, that also extends **"Base" but it has a job attribute**:

```
class Worker(Base):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Jobs, on_delete=models.CASCADE ...)
```

##### Implementation

Here's an example of how they can be instantiated:

```
Company.objects.create(name='Company1', 
                       belongs_to=None) # This will also create a Base Object with the ID 1.


Manager.objects.create(name='Manager1', 
                       belongs_to=1 [[company]], 
                       role=1)  # This will create a Manager object and relate it to the Company. 
# (And also create a Company object with the ID 2, that don't make much sense, but is only an abstract example)

Worker.objects.create(name='Worker1', 
                      belongs_to=2 [[manager]], job=1) # In this case, I'm saying that the Worker is grouped under the Manager Object.
```

The Idea is that, the Worker can also **not have a manager** and be directly related under a **Company**, like:

```
(...)

Worker.objects.create(name='Worker34', 
                      belongs_to=1 [[company]], 
                      job=1) # In this case, I'm saying that the "Worker" is grouped under the "Company" Object.
```

## Django Rest and Question Wrap-up:

**Now to the DJANGO REST in to my question:**

I'm using serializer.ModelSerializer *(since I don't have much experience with Software Architecture, and I'm trying the keep it as simple and efficient as possible)* with the `'Meta'` `depth` to have **Nested Objects**:

##### serializer.py

```
class WorkerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 3
```

But since the field `belongs_to` is an attribute of the **Base** ***it returns only the information Containing in Base***, like this:

```
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Worker1,
        "belongs_to": {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "Manager1",
            ****this is where I would like to have the aditional Manager Object info."
            "belongs_to": {
                "id": 1,
                "nome": "Company1",
            }
        },
    },
```

In this example, **I would need the Manager 'roles' attribute from the Roles Table** (Omitted in this example), to also retrieve information from there.

Is there any way I can point to the Serializer that It should First try to see if the 'belongs' to point to a higher chain object or since it is an attribute of base, It'll only return the Base attributes serialized

Is it possible, is it viable and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the field reference in serializers with another serializers. Like:

```
class ManagerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Manager
        fields = '__all__'

class WorkerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    belongs_to = ManagerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = '__all__'
```

That way you can return more details about a field in a ForeingKey relationship